# Not understanding shared instance

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am getting confused about how to use shared instance.

This is my set up:

```
+ (ViewController *)sharedInstance {

   static ViewController *_sharedInstance = nil;
   if (_sharedInstance == nil) {
       _sharedInstance = [[ViewController alloc] init];
   }
   return _sharedInstance;
}
```

I also have a property in the `ViewController.h` file called
`@property (nonatomic, retain) CBPeripheral * selectedPeripheral;` and under the interface in the `ViewController.m` file `CBPeripheral     * _selectedPeripheral;` and I make sure to `synthesize them`

So whenever I do this. It works.

```
 [ViewController sharedInstance].selectedPeripheral = _selectedPeripheral;
 NSLog(@"_sharedInstance %@", [[ViewController sharedInstance] selectedPeripheral]);
```

But if I do this? Without doing the line above. It returns null?
I thought the synthesize would make it so I don't have to assign it again?

```
 NSLog(@"_sharedInstance %@", [[ViewController sharedInstance] selectedPeripheral]);
```

Comment: "and I make sure to synthesize them" does what mean exactly? Where do you have your "testing" code?

Comment: @Eiko I have `@synthesize selectedPeripheral = _selectedPeripheral;` I have the testing code in the same file. But I have tried in other files as well and they both return null.

Comment: Where are you getting `_selectedPeripheral` from?  Are you setting the ivar in your `init` method, and have you overridden your `-init` method?  Also, in what file does this line reside:  `[ViewController sharedInstance].selectedPeripheral = _selectedPeripheral;`?

Comment: the `[ViewController sharedInstance].selectedPeripheral = _selectedPeripheral;` resides in the `ViewController.m` file. The `_selectedPeripheral` is an `ivar` mentioned in the question. How do I set an `CBPeripheral` in my init and I am not overriding my init method.

Comment: Did you override the setter as well?

Answer (score 0):

You are not assigning any value to `_selectedPeripheral`, thus, is has no value.

Try setting `_selectedPeripheral` inside your singleton initializer.

I don't know anything about the code, but it implies something needs to be selected. You may have an issue in your selection code as well, but you're class won't magically create objects because it is a singleton ;-)

**EDIT**

`@synthesize` only creates the instance variavle (the underscored), so it is available from inside your class. Note this is only necessary, if you overwrite getter and setter as well.

Also note that you posted the getter of the singleton and you have problems with a property. Please poste the code we need to see to help you without guessing.